# SQL 2014 Install failed to install Data Services and SSAS, rest is installed, how to fix without uninstall?

Tags: sql-server, installation

I just installed SQL 2014 trial version, but it failed to install SQL Data Services and SSAS Services due to space issues, which have been resolved.

How can I re-install only those services without having to uninstall the entire thing? I tried Repair and that doesn't do it.

Comment: Can you just "add" those as new features?

Comment: No, tried that too.